# Executable isn't made in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, qt5, qmake

I tried to make the executable of my qt quick program. But when I do so there isn't any executable file is generated. Even though  I unchecked the shadow building. I searched through many websites and found a video about it where he runs the `qmake` and then `make` to generate the executable file. But nothing happened. I even set the build directory to my current project directory. Apart from it I even did this for the QWidget application and the result was the same. There was no executable. Please help me out.[image: Here is my build and run configuration][image: Build settings]

[image: Trial folder]
[image: compilation and run from terminal]

```
17:36:05: Running steps for project Keba_1...
17:36:05: Starting: "/home/stpl/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake" /home/stpl/Keba_1/Keba_1.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler
17:36:05: The process "/home/stpl/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake" exited normally.
17:36:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
17:36:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
17:36:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
17:36:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
17:36:05: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

[image: project file]

Please check this out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not have a .exe extension as Windows (maybe you're used to that?)

The circled item is the executable:

[image: The circled item is the executable]

Comment: exactly that is the file

Comment: Qt output generates an executable every time. I saw this in the previous versions. But don't know why it's happening this time.

Comment: @k111 what is happening?

Comment: No, it is not. When you open the executable, your application opens up. And it is showing the shared library file. When I tried to open this it is working at all.

Comment: @k111 isn't that the goal - to start (open) your application?

Comment: I think the Compile output does not show the name of the executable since no code was changed

Comment: I want to run this application on other devices too. And there is always an executable there as per I know.

Comment: @k111 Do you mean like Android devices or what?

Comment: @scopchanov I want to run it on a terminal device as a solo application.

Comment: @k111 
The compilation offered by Linux by default comes with a dynamic link so if you want to share it in another OS you will have to do a deployment, for example if you want to share it in another Ubuntu you should create a .deb or use snap.

Comment: @k111, I think you use the wrong terms and that confuses the people, so no one is able to actually help you. Please, clarify what exactly do you want to achieve, since this is not what the title of this question says.